# UnauthorizedAccessException вылетает при чтении файла

Tags: c#, .net

У меня имеется файл (мой файл, не сторонней программы), находящийся в директории C:\ProgramData.... Вся проблема в том, что я не могу его прочитать. Процесс, который пытается прочитать файл является сервисом, запущенный как NT AUTHORITY\СИСТЕМА, в манифесте приложения права "highestAvailable". Читаю простым методом File.ReadAllLines().

Comment: ну вы уверены, что у этого юзера есть права на чтение того файла?

Comment: @tym32167 мне кажется, если я от имени системы (с такими же правами запускаются csrss, lsass , т.е крайне важные системные процессы, то я имею такие же права как и они

Comment: @tym32167 а они читать могут что захотят

Comment: Вот смотрите - вы говорите, что запускаете ПО от имени системы и оно не может прочитать файл. Варианта два - либо у системы нет доступа на чтение файла, и надо увеличивать и прописывать права явно, либо вы ошибаетесь, что запустили ПО от нужного юзера - и тогда вам надо исследовать что вы делаете не так при запуске.

Comment: @tym32167 еще дополнение: раньше (месяц назад) все работало, возможно, обновление Windows сыграло роль или что-то в этом роде. Также, я обновил Kaspersky Internet Security с 18 на 19 версию. Думаю антивирус может блокировать, так как там целый гиг файлов обновлений, патчей в ProgramData\Kaspersky Lab.

Comment: может быть, но это уже только вы сами можете выяснить :)

Comment: @tym32167 я сделал проще - просто перенес все обновления моей проги в папку Appdata\roaming. Там на всех компьютерах есть доступ

Comment: Тоже годится как решение :). Только почему Roaming, а не, например, Local?

Comment: @tym32167 можно и в локал, только сейчас для теста юзаю roaming. как в продакшн пойдет там все будет в локале

Comment: друг дело, плюсую :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема была в том, что каким-то образом доступа к папке не было. Пересоздав папку, проблема решилась.